# selenium error firefox 82.0.3 win 10 64 bit

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

0.3 win 10 64 bit and am just writing my first selenium but its unsuccessful bcuz of this error here is my code

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

sleep(5)

browser.close()
```

and its is my wy way long error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SuperUser_ROOT\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\SuperUser_ROOT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\SuperUser_ROOT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SuperUser_ROOT/Desktop/Projects/TRANSpy.py", line 4, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\SuperUser_ROOT\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\SuperUser_ROOT\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```